# PHP strtotime doesnt want to work

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

If I have the following code:

```
var_dump(strtotime('2:28:15am 28/11/2013'));
```

It returns false. What is causing this?

Comment: strtotime is good, but it's not omniscient and can NOT handle many formats, including this one. What it **can** handle is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That format is probably not a format that [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) can interpret. Try using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i:sa d/j/Y', '2:28:15am 28/11/2013');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I had to guess at the exact formatting of your dates. But you can easily edit that by using the appropriate formatting options [listed here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thanks, I can use $dt->format('U') to get out the unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your time format, strtotime works with the following format for sure:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
strtotime($date);
```